# Autocomplete database or cleansing

Tags: civimember, contacts

As I begin entering the city St. Paul, the helpful hint pops up with St. Paul, but with a street address following.  Is there a way to eliminate the street address. (Find autocomplete contact metadata?)

Comment: William - you might need to provide some more information. Your comment about 'prior login' - login to what?

Comment: is this a custom form ? as I think core civi doesn't have an autocomplete for City anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Search Preferences, and beside Autocomplete Contact Search and/or Contact Reference Options disable Street Address and possibly other fields.